# Nodejs 2nd call on same external API return previous result

Tags: node.js, node-fetch

I am writing a service In which I have to register an order tracking number to an external source to track my order automatically.

```
let trackingObj = {
    tracking: {
        tracking_number: params.trackingNumber,
        order_id: params.orderId,
        emails: params.email,
        smses: params.phoneNumber,
        note: params.optIn
    }
}
const aftershipTracking = await AftershipService.postTrackingInfo(trackingObj);
```

```
postTrackingInfo: async (body) => {
    let _URL = helper.env('AFTER_SHIP_API_URL') + 'trackings';
    return await ((await fetch(_URL, {
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify(body),
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
            'aftership-api-key': helper.env('AFTER_SHIP_API_KEY')
        },
    })).json());
}
```

When I make the first call to register the tracking number, it returns an immediate default object with tag pending.

This returns me which is expected behavior

```
{
    "meta": {
        "code": 201
    },
    "data": {
        "tracking": {
            "id": "xyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyxxyzxyxzxyz",
            "created_at": "2020-06-25T14:22:09+00:00",
            "updated_at": "2020-06-25T14:22:09+00:00",
            "last_updated_at": "2020-06-25T14:22:09+00:00",
            "tracking_number": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
            "slug": "fedex",
            "active": true,
            "android": [],
            "custom_fields": null,
            "customer_name": null,
            "delivery_time": null,
            "destination_country_iso3": null,
            "courier_destination_country_iso3": null,
            "emails": [],
            "expected_delivery": null,
            "ios": [],
            "note": null,
            "order_id": null,
            "order_id_path": null,
            "origin_country_iso3": null,
            "shipment_package_count": null,
            "shipment_pickup_date": null,
            "shipment_delivery_date": null,
            "shipment_type": null,
            "shipment_weight": null,
            "shipment_weight_unit": null,
            "signed_by": null,
            "smses": [],
            "source": "api",
            "tag": "Pending",
            "subtag": "Pending_001",
            "subtag_message": "Pending",
            "title": "642028981335",
            "tracked_count": 0,
            "last_mile_tracking_supported": null,
            "language": null,
            "unique_token": "deprecated",
            "checkpoints": [],
            "subscribed_smses": [],
            "subscribed_emails": [],
            "return_to_sender": false,
            "order_promised_delivery_date": null,
            "delivery_type": null,
            "pickup_location": null,
            "pickup_note": null,
            "courier_tracking_link": "https://www.fedex.com/apps/fedextrack/?tracknumbers=642028981335&cntry_code=US",
            "first_attempted_at": null,
            "courier_redirect_link": "https://www.fedex.com/apps/fedextrack/?action=track&tracknumbers=642028981335&cntry_code=US",
            "tracking_account_number": null,
            "tracking_origin_country": null,
            "tracking_destination_country": null,
            "tracking_key": null,
            "tracking_postal_code": null,
            "tracking_ship_date": null,
            "tracking_state": null
        }
    }
}
```

To get the latest or current tag of a tracking number, I have to make back to back the second request to the same external source with the different endpoint. This has to return the latest information this is what happening in Postman but not happening in Nodejs.

```
const aftershipTrackingStatus = await AftershipService.getTrackingInfo(aftershipTracking.data.tracking.slug, params.trackingNumber);
```

```
getTrackingInfo: async (slug, trackingNumber) => {
    let _URL = helper.env('AFTER_SHIP_API_URL') + 'trackings/' + slug + '/' + trackingNumber;
    return await ((await fetch(_URL, {
        method: 'GET',
        body: null,
        headers: {
            'aftership-api-key': helper.env('AFTER_SHIP_API_KEY')
        },
    })).json());
},
```

**This again returns me the same result as above in 2nd block which is not expected.**

As per Postman, it should return this.

```
{
    "meta": {
        "code": 200
    },
    "data": {
        "tracking": {
            "id": "xyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyz",
            "created_at": "2020-06-25T06:09:07+00:00",
            "updated_at": "2020-06-25T06:09:41+00:00",
            "last_updated_at": "2020-06-25T06:09:41+00:00",
            "tracking_number": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
            "slug": "fedex",
            "active": false,
            "android": [],
            "custom_fields": null,
            "customer_name": null,
            "delivery_time": 7,
            "destination_country_iso3": "USA",
            "courier_destination_country_iso3": "USA",
            "emails": [],
            "expected_delivery": null,
            "ios": [],
            "note": null,
            "order_id": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
            "order_id_path": null,
            "origin_country_iso3": "USA",
            "shipment_package_count": 1,
            "shipment_pickup_date": "2020-06-03T06:00:00",
            "shipment_delivery_date": "2020-06-09T21:17:56",
            "shipment_type": "FedEx Ground",
            "shipment_weight": 11.3,
            "shipment_weight_unit": "lb",
            "signed_by": "Signature not required",
            "smses": [],
            "source": "api",
            "tag": "Delivered",
            "subtag": "Delivered_001",
            "subtag_message": "Delivered",
            "title": "642028981335",
            "tracked_count": 1,
            "last_mile_tracking_supported": null,
            "language": null,
            "unique_token": "deprecated",
            "checkpoints": [
                {
                    "slug": "fedex",
                    "city": null,
                    "created_at": "2020-06-25T06:09:41+00:00",
                    "location": null,
                    "country_name": null,
                    "message": "Shipment information sent to FedEx",
                    "country_iso3": null,
                    "tag": "InfoReceived",
                    "subtag": "InfoReceived_001",
                    "subtag_message": "Info Received",
                    "checkpoint_time": "2020-06-03T12:48:00-04:00",
                    "coordinates": [],
                    "state": null,
                    "zip": null,
                    "raw_tag": "OC"
                },
                {
                    "slug": "fedex",
                    "city": "AUSTELL",
                    "created_at": "2020-06-25T06:09:41+00:00",
                    "location": "AUSTELL, GA",
                    "country_name": null,
                    "message": "Picked up",
                    "country_iso3": null,
                    "tag": "InTransit",
                    "subtag": "InTransit_002",
                    "subtag_message": "Acceptance scan",
                    "checkpoint_time": "2020-06-03T15:37:00-04:00",
                    "coordinates": [],
                    "state": "GA",
                    "zip": null,
                    "raw_tag": "PU"
                },
                {
                    "slug": "fedex",
                    "city": "AUSTELL",
                    "created_at": "2020-06-25T06:09:41+00:00",
                    "location": "AUSTELL, GA",
                    "country_name": null,
                    "message": "Arrived at FedEx location",
                    "country_iso3": null,
                    "tag": "InTransit",
                    "subtag": "InTransit_003",
                    "subtag_message": "Arrival scan",
                    "checkpoint_time": "2020-06-03T17:52:00-04:00",
                    "coordinates": [],
                    "state": "GA",
                    "zip": null,
                    "raw_tag": "AR"
                },
                {
                    "slug": "fedex",
                    "city": "AUSTELL",
                    "created_at": "2020-06-25T06:09:41+00:00",
                    "location": "AUSTELL, GA",
                    "country_name": null,
                    "message": "Left FedEx origin facility",
                    "country_iso3": null,
                    "tag": "InTransit",
                    "subtag": "InTransit_007",
                    "subtag_message": "Departure Scan",
                    "checkpoint_time": "2020-06-04T01:13:35-04:00",
                    "coordinates": [],
                    "state": "GA",
                    "zip": null,
                    "raw_tag": "DP"
                },
                {
                    "slug": "fedex",
                    "city": "POWDER SPRINGS",
                    "created_at": "2020-06-25T06:09:41+00:00",
                    "location": "POWDER SPRINGS, GA",
                    "country_name": null,
                    "message": "In transit",
                    "country_iso3": null,
                    "tag": "InTransit",
                    "subtag": "InTransit_001",
                    "subtag_message": "In Transit",
                    "checkpoint_time": "2020-06-04T13:19:27-04:00",
                    "coordinates": [],
                    "state": "GA",
                    "zip": null,
                    "raw_tag": "IT"
                },
                {
                    "slug": "fedex",
                    "city": "FORREST CITY",
                    "created_at": "2020-06-25T06:09:41+00:00",
                    "location": "FORREST CITY, AR",
                    "country_name": null,
                    "message": "In transit",
                    "country_iso3": null,
                    "tag": "InTransit",
                    "subtag": "InTransit_001",
                    "subtag_message": "In Transit",
                    "checkpoint_time": "2020-06-05T00:19:37-05:00",
                    "coordinates": [],
                    "state": "AR",
                    "zip": null,
                    "raw_tag": "IT"
                },
                {
                    "slug": "fedex",
                    "city": "PANHANDLE",
                    "created_at": "2020-06-25T06:09:41+00:00",
                    "location": "PANHANDLE, TX",
                    "country_name": null,
                    "message": "In transit",
                    "country_iso3": null,
                    "tag": "InTransit",
                    "subtag": "InTransit_001",
                    "subtag_message": "In Transit",
                    "checkpoint_time": "2020-06-05T12:21:24-05:00",
                    "coordinates": [],
                    "state": "TX",
                    "zip": null,
                    "raw_tag": "IT"
                },
                {
                    "slug": "fedex",
                    "city": "WILLIAMS",
                    "created_at": "2020-06-25T06:09:41+00:00",
                    "location": "WILLIAMS, AZ",
                    "country_name": null,
                    "message": "In transit",
                    "country_iso3": null,
                    "tag": "InTransit",
                    "subtag": "InTransit_001",
                    "subtag_message": "In Transit",
                    "checkpoint_time": "2020-06-05T22:24:11-07:00",
                    "coordinates": [],
                    "state": "AZ",
                    "zip": null,
                    "raw_tag": "IT"
                },
                {
                    "slug": "fedex",
                    "city": "TRACY",
                    "created_at": "2020-06-25T06:09:41+00:00",
                    "location": "TRACY, CA",
                    "country_name": null,
                    "message": "In transit",
                    "country_iso3": null,
                    "tag": "InTransit",
                    "subtag": "InTransit_001",
                    "subtag_message": "In Transit",
                    "checkpoint_time": "2020-06-06T17:25:49-07:00",
                    "coordinates": [],
                    "state": "CA",
                    "zip": null,
                    "raw_tag": "IT"
                },
                {
                    "slug": "fedex",
                    "city": "TRACY",
                    "created_at": "2020-06-25T06:09:41+00:00",
                    "location": "TRACY, CA",
                    "country_name": null,
                    "message": "In transit",
                    "country_iso3": null,
                    "tag": "InTransit",
                    "subtag": "InTransit_001",
                    "subtag_message": "In Transit",
                    "checkpoint_time": "2020-06-07T06:03:27-07:00",
                    "coordinates": [],
                    "state": "CA",
                    "zip": null,
                    "raw_tag": "IT"
                },
                {
                    "slug": "fedex",
                    "city": "TRACY",
                    "created_at": "2020-06-25T06:09:41+00:00",
                    "location": "TRACY, CA",
                    "country_name": null,
                    "message": "In transit",
                    "country_iso3": null,
                    "tag": "InTransit",
                    "subtag": "InTransit_001",
                    "subtag_message": "In Transit",
                    "checkpoint_time": "2020-06-07T18:03:54-07:00",
                    "coordinates": [],
                    "state": "CA",
                    "zip": null,
                    "raw_tag": "IT"
                },
                {
                    "slug": "fedex",
                    "city": "TRACY",
                    "created_at": "2020-06-25T06:09:41+00:00",
                    "location": "TRACY, CA",
                    "country_name": null,
                    "message": "In transit",
                    "country_iso3": null,
                    "tag": "InTransit",
                    "subtag": "InTransit_001",
                    "subtag_message": "In Transit",
                    "checkpoint_time": "2020-06-08T06:04:14-07:00",
                    "coordinates": [],
                    "state": "CA",
                    "zip": null,
                    "raw_tag": "IT"
                },
                {
                    "slug": "fedex",
                    "city": "TRACY",
                    "created_at": "2020-06-25T06:09:41+00:00",
                    "location": "TRACY, CA",
                    "country_name": null,
                    "message": "Arrived at FedEx location",
                    "country_iso3": null,
                    "tag": "InTransit",
                    "subtag": "InTransit_003",
                    "subtag_message": "Arrival scan",
                    "checkpoint_time": "2020-06-08T21:04:00-07:00",
                    "coordinates": [],
                    "state": "CA",
                    "zip": null,
                    "raw_tag": "AR"
                },
                {
                    "slug": "fedex",
                    "city": "TRACY",
                    "created_at": "2020-06-25T06:09:41+00:00",
                    "location": "TRACY, CA",
                    "country_name": null,
                    "message": "Departed FedEx location",
                    "country_iso3": null,
                    "tag": "InTransit",
                    "subtag": "InTransit_007",
                    "subtag_message": "Departure Scan",
                    "checkpoint_time": "2020-06-08T23:34:27-07:00",
                    "coordinates": [],
                    "state": "CA",
                    "zip": null,
                    "raw_tag": "DP"
                },
                {
                    "slug": "fedex",
                    "city": "SAN LEANDRO",
                    "created_at": "2020-06-25T06:09:41+00:00",
                    "location": "SAN LEANDRO, CA",
                    "country_name": null,
                    "message": "At local FedEx facility",
                    "country_iso3": null,
                    "tag": "InTransit",
                    "subtag": "InTransit_007",
                    "subtag_message": "Departure Scan",
                    "checkpoint_time": "2020-06-09T04:36:00-07:00",
                    "coordinates": [],
                    "state": "CA",
                    "zip": null,
                    "raw_tag": "AR"
                },
                {
                    "slug": "fedex",
                    "city": "SAN LEANDRO",
                    "created_at": "2020-06-25T06:09:41+00:00",
                    "location": "SAN LEANDRO, CA",
                    "country_name": null,
                    "message": "On FedEx vehicle for delivery",
                    "country_iso3": null,
                    "tag": "OutForDelivery",
                    "subtag": "OutForDelivery_001",
                    "subtag_message": "Out for Delivery",
                    "checkpoint_time": "2020-06-09T04:48:00-07:00",
                    "coordinates": [],
                    "state": "CA",
                    "zip": null,
                    "raw_tag": "OD"
                },
                {
                    "slug": "fedex",
                    "city": "Oakland",
                    "created_at": "2020-06-25T06:09:41+00:00",
                    "location": "Oakland, CA",
                    "country_name": null,
                    "message": "Delivered - Left at front door. Signature Service not requested.",
                    "country_iso3": null,
                    "tag": "Delivered",
                    "subtag": "Delivered_001",
                    "subtag_message": "Delivered",
                    "checkpoint_time": "2020-06-09T14:17:56-07:00",
                    "coordinates": [],
                    "state": "CA",
                    "zip": null,
                    "raw_tag": "DL"
                }
            ],
            "subscribed_smses": [],
            "subscribed_emails": [],
            "return_to_sender": false,
            "order_promised_delivery_date": null,
            "delivery_type": null,
            "pickup_location": null,
            "pickup_note": null,
            "courier_tracking_link": "https://www.fedex.com/apps/fedextrack/?tracknumbers=642028981335&cntry_code=US",
            "first_attempted_at": "2020-06-09T14:17:56-07:00",
            "courier_redirect_link": "https://www.fedex.com/apps/fedextrack/?action=track&tracknumbers=642028981335&cntry_code=US",
            "tracking_account_number": null,
            "tracking_origin_country": null,
            "tracking_destination_country": null,
            "tracking_key": null,
            "tracking_postal_code": null,
            "tracking_ship_date": null,
            "tracking_state": null
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you share the code where you are calling `postTrackingInfo` and `getTrackingInfo`  functions  ?

Comment: @Ezzat code updated. both calls are back to back.

Comment: are you sure the 2nd parameter (trackingNumber) shouldn't be the tracking id returned from the first call in `aftershipTracking.data.tracking.id`?

Comment: Your code seems correct , you need to check `helper.env('AFTER_SHIP_API_URL')` and log the responses to debug this issue

Comment: @AlwaysLearning yes per API it is trackingNumber

https://docs.aftership.com/api/4/trackings/get-trackings-slug-tracking_number

Comment: @Ezzat I am debugging but it is returning the result of 1st API call on 2nd API call. I dont know why.

Comment: The docs also say `You can always use /:id to replace /:slug/:tracking_number` so maybe try that and see if it gives a different response

Comment: @AlwaysLearning Dear if you open the link. There is no endpoint to serve :id in place of slug and tracking_number.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning and suppose I can replace id with slug and tracking_number. Why it is working perfectly fine in Postman?

Comment: can you console.log the 2nd URL to compare against the one used in postman?